# ModPagespeedEnableFilters insert_ga - inserting the tracking code with a condition if (window.parent == window)

Tags: google-analytics, mod-pagespeed

ModPagespeedEnableFilters insert_ga - inserting the tracking code with a condition if (window.parent == window)

Below is the Tracking code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.parent == window) {
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'XXXXX']);
        _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'abc.def.com']);
        _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); 
    ga.type = 'text/javascript';
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = 'https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js';

    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
}</script>
```

Problem : Our website uses frame so the above check is causing problem for the child frame.

How can I remove the check from the Tracking Code that is automatically generated by Apache pagespeed.